# Removing quotes in string interpolation

Tags: python, odoo

In Python, I am building a string to be used as a condition in another function.

```
po_id_criteria = "('id','='," + str(ids[0]) + ")"
po_ids = po_obj.search(cr, uid, [('state','in',['sourced','confirmed','confirmed_wait','approved']),po_id_criteria])
```

And get an error, because the double quotes are being added:

```
ValueError: Bad domain expression: [('active', '=', 1), ('state', 'in', ['sourced', 'confirmed', 'confirmed_wait', 'approved']), "('id','=',1)"]
```

I really want it without the double quotes, ie:

```
[('active', '=', 1), ('state', 'in', ['sourced', 'confirmed', 'confirmed_wait', 'approved']), ('id','=',1)]
```

Comment: Why create a string? Why don't you just make a tuple instead with `po_id_criteria = ('id','=', ids[0])`?

Comment: Then why are you building a string at all? Why not just build the tuple? `po_id_criteria = ('id','=', ids[0])`

Comment: It seems you want a tuple for your pe_id_criteria, but you are creating a string. Why not simply create what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want it without quotes, write it without quotes:

```
 po_id_criteria = ( 'id','=', ids[0] )
```